# PHP Namespace and includes

Tags: php, parse-platform, namespaces

I am using Parse and Composer. I'm new to the new Namespacing convention in PHP. So I have the following in my index file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');

use Parse\ParseQuery;
$businessQuery = new ParseQuery("Businesses");
$businessQuery->equalTo("Active", true);
$businessQuery->limit(1);
$businessQuery->ascending("Name");
$businessResults = $businessQuery->find();

include_once 'whatever.php';
```

Then I have a include file, which appears to not play nicely as 'ParseQuery' fails in whatever.php. So what am I doing wrong? Please tell me it's an easy fix! lol

```
<?
$homeQuery = new ParseQuery("Photos");
?>
```

**Fatal error:  Class 'ParseQuery' not found in /Website/whatever.php on line 4**

Answer (score 0):

You must set correct autoloader in composer.json [here is example](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). About PHP autoloading convention you can [read here](http://www.php-fig.org/).